Vercel with Python and Flask, subdomains
Sooo what I'm trying is to add subdomains to my main domain on Vercel app with Python and Flask, and I was researching info for this, so my actual server is working like this:
api.example.com with some routes.
EDIT:

The project is already deployed with single api.example.com and is working pretty well.

Now i want to add another subdomain link.example.com.
so if I'm accessing api.example.com/ -> { "message": "hello" }
and if I'm accessing link.example.com/ -> { "message": "link hello" }
FOR REAL IT TOOK TO ME DAYS and i can not find anything useful on internet, Thank you in advance.
Here is my code:
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import cross_origin
from bot import carburantBot
from commons import constants
from services import (
    startV1,
    tokenV1,
    gasStationsV1,
    gasStationInfoV1,
    gasStationHistoricPricesV1,
    gasStationServicesV1,
    gasStationDiscountsV1,
    sendEmailV1,
    carburantTypesV1,
)

from middleware.auth import requires_auth

app = Flask(__name__)
bot = carburantBot.GetBot()

@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_ROOT, methods=constants.GET)
def home():
    return jsonify(constants.MESSAGE_ROOT)


@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_START_V1, methods=constants.GET)
def start():
    return jsonify({"start": startV1.responseV1()})


@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_TOKEN_V1, methods=constants.POST)
def token():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    result = tokenV1.responseV1(request_data)
    return jsonify({"token": result})


@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_CARBURANT_TYPES_V1, methods=constants.GET)
@cross_origin(headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
@requires_auth
def carburantTypes():
    result = carburantTypesV1.responseV1()
    return jsonify({"gasProductsList": result})


@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_GAS_STATIONS_V1, methods=constants.POST)
@cross_origin(headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
@requires_auth
def gasStations():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    result = gasStationsV1.responseV1(request_data)
    return jsonify(result)


@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_GAS_STATION_INFO_V1, methods=constants.POST)
@cross_origin(headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
@requires_auth
def gasStationInfo():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    result = gasStationInfoV1.responseV1(request_data)
    return jsonify(result)


@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_GAS_STATION_HISTORIC_PRICES_V1, methods=constants.POST)
@cross_origin(headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
@requires_auth
def gasStationHistoricPrices():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    result = gasStationHistoricPricesV1.responseV1(request_data)
    return jsonify(result)


@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_GAS_STATION_SERVICES_V1, methods=constants.POST)
@cross_origin(headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
@requires_auth
def gasStationServices():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    result = gasStationServicesV1.responseV1(request_data)
    return jsonify(result)


@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_GAS_STATION_DISCOUNTS_V1, methods=constants.POST)
@cross_origin(headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
@requires_auth
def gasStationDiscounts():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    result = gasStationDiscountsV1.responseV1(request_data)
    return jsonify(result)


@app.route(constants.ENDPOINT_SEND_EMAIL_V1, methods=constants.POST)
@cross_origin(headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
@requires_auth
def sendEmail():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    result = sendEmailV1.responseV1(request_data)
    return jsonify({"status": result})


# ERRORHandler

@app.errorhandler(400)
def badRequest():
    return jsonify(constants.ERROR_400), 400


@app.errorhandler(401)
def pageNotAuthorized(*args, **kwargs):
    return jsonify(constants.ERROR_401), 401

@app.errorhandler(403)
def tokenExpired(*args, **kwargs):
    return jsonify(constants.ERROR_403), 401

@app.errorhandler(404)
def pageNotFound(error):
    return jsonify(constants.ERROR_404), 404


@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(error):
    return jsonify(constants.ERROR_500), 500


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=constants.SERVER_PORT)



Does this help? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/#SERVER_NAME

Or perhaps https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/appdispatch/#dispatch-by-subdomain
